# Inside a combo box and multicombo box I need to make specific value as graded out.(for this we are getting a flag from Odata)

Tags: sapui5

```
<ComboBox items="{ProductModel>FIELDTOVAL/results}"&nbsp;
                    change='onSelectionChange' visible="{parts:[{path:'ProductModel>FIELDTOVAL/results/1/Valuedesc'},{path:'ProductModel>Fieldselmode'},{path:'ProductModel>Fieldname'}] ,formatter:'.comboboxVisibility'}">
                    <core:Item key="{ProductModel>Valueid}" text="{ProductModel>Valuedesc}" enabled ="path:'ProductModel>Valuedefault',formatter:'.combodefault'}" />
```

}

```
combodefault:function(cd){
return(cd ==="X")?false:true;}
```

[Resulting combobox post applying formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HYZJ.png) We have a requirement where inside a `sap.m.ComboBox` and `sap.m.MultiComboBox` we need to show values as greyed out ones.
If the flag from our Odata-Service has `Valuedefault = "X"` then the specific value should be greyed out.Please note we are using XML-View. Getting confused which property of UI controls can be used. Any suggestions on the same please.

Regards,
Ranjan R

Comment: [Disable item inside combo box SAPUI5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937113/disable-item-inside-combo-box-sapui5/52941951)

Comment: Hi Najzs,
Thanks for the response, I have added formatter for 'core:Item' using enabled property. and resulting image also added for combobox. I can see it is working for combobox but not for multicombobox. Infact the same 'core:Item' we have used for multicombobox too. Please let me know do we need to enable any other property for items of multicombobox?

Comment: Which UI5 version is used ?

Comment: Hi,
Its 1.38.30

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Expression Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.32.9/docs/guide/5cff8d1c3fb84c5db7a00f2daca125af.html).

```
<ComboBox items="{/myEntity}">
  <core:Item key="{key}" text="{text}" enabled="{= ${Valuedefault} !== 'X'}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Hi Alex,
Thanks for the response, I have added formatter for 'core:Item' using enabled property. and resulting image also added for combobox. I can see it is working for combobox but not for multicombobox. Infact the same 'core:Item' we have used for multicombobox too. Please let me know do we need to enable any other property for items of multicombobox?

Comment: Hi Alex,
this enabled property worked for combobox and it is disabling the specific items inside the combobox. 
But the same is not working for Multicombobox , I used enabled property as `<core:ListItem key="{ProductModel>Valueid}" text="{ProductModel>Valuedesc}" enabled="{=${ProductModel>Valuedefault} !=='X'}"  /> 
`  but this is deleting the specific value from the list inside multicombobox instead of greyed out. could you please let me know in SAP UI5 multicombobox can we disable(make the data as greyed out) the specific item or do we need to remove it(is this a standard behaviour).

Comment: Disbled items in MultiCombox will be removed. That's the standard behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex